# Network timed out exception

Tags: android, sockets, connection, arduino, timed

I have an Android application which connects to an Arduino server and sends it sockets on a button press, but as soon as I press the button it waits a little while and then throws "Connection timed out". I know the Arduino works; I tried it over the browser and it was fine. Why can't my application access it?

The Android code:

```
Button.OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(Tag,"connecting to Server");
        try {
            Log.i(Tag,"Enters try");
            socket = new Socket("161.53.168.112", 8888);
            Log.i(Tag,"stvorio socket");
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());//and stream

            Log.i(Tag,"Writing 1 on socket.");
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("1");
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.i(Tag,e.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(Tag,e.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Tag, e.toString());
```

And here is the code used in the Arduino. It's quite simple, so I can't understand what went wrong. I used many logs, because I wanted to see where the mistake is. I use my Arduino as a server and post something on it. If I type in 161.53.168.112:8888 in a web browser, it finds it and can send a request but my Android phone gets nothing, even using the browser, and not an app. I can't access my server. AM I maybe missing some permission in the server or on the Android?

```
byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x00, 0x36, 0xFF };
byte ip[] = { 161, 53, 168, 114 };
int serverPort = 8888;

#define kitchenLight = 9;

Server server(serverPort);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
    pinMode(kitchenLight,OUTPUT);
    server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    Client client = server.available();
    if(client)
    {
        while(client.connected()) {
            if(client.available()) {
                char c = client.read();
                appMessage += c;
                if (c == '\n')
                {
                    Serial.println("Message from Client: "+appMessage);

                    if(appMessage.IndexOf("kitchenLight1") != -1)
                    {
                        digitalWrite(kitchenLight,HIGH);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    client.close();
}
```

Comment: Post your code, and more about how you tested with the browser...

Comment: I added code in my question...

Comment: Do you mean that it works from the browser on the phone, but not from the app you created on the phone? If so ensure you added Uses Permission INTERNET to your apps manifest.

Comment: Yes I added that permission and no it doesn't work from the browser on the phone, phone seems to be unable to connect to the server at all, but there was no problem with PC

Comment: Is the phone on the same network as the Arduino (Sorry have to ask). Also is the PC connect to the network via ethernet or wifi? And how is the arduino connected to the network? While I was playing with similar stuff I could never get a phone connected via wifi to talk with an arduino connected via cable. I got a wifi chip for my arduino though, and if I serve the content from the arduino with that, the phone can connect to it via wifi. I never did figure out why

Comment: Arduino and PC are both with ethernet cables connected to network and phone is ofcourse trying to communicate via wifi. So you think there is no way I'll manage to do it this way? Do you think if I somehow manage to find server with browser on phone, app would also able to do it, I mean there won't be any more permissions or firewalls to think of,cause one of my colegues had arduino as server and no problems with connecting it over phone browser but it wasn't android or app but I know he sended requests over wifi to ethernet connected arduino server

Comment: I imagine there is a way to do it, But I didn't manage to get it working with the arduino plugged in via ethernet. Once I switched my arduino to wifi though instead of ethernet I got the connection working. And yes I think if it works in the stock browser it should also work within your application.

Answer (score 0):

After you make a connection between your Arduino and Android, you should add a delay, like, for a second or two (more likely two), because it takes that time for Arduino to get ready receiving commands.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: try System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false") this will solve your connection timeout problem.